# R ggplot2 - barplot with multiple x and y values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot 3 different mean values (Mean1, Mean2 and Mean3) for 4 different species (A, B, C and D). I have 1 mean value per species and per years (2005, 2013 and 2022).
Here is my R code (doesn't work):

ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction (Species, Year), y = c(Mean1, Mean2, Mean3, Mean4), fill = c(Mean1, Mean2, Mean3, Mean4)) +
geom_bar(position = "stack", stat="identity")

I am trying to make the same type of barplot as shown on the picture on R but I don't manage to have all the mean (Mean1, Mean2, Mean3) on the same plot because they all come from a different column of my dataframe (see table on the image).

[image]

Is it possible to have more than one "fill" variable ? Or something else to obtain the same plot ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's not the way ggplot2 works. For your case you have to reshape your data to long or tidy format, e.g. try `df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(c(Mean1, Mean2, Mean3, Mean4), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% ggplot(aes(x = interaction (Species, Year), y = value, fill = name) + geom_bar(position = "stack", stat="identity")`. If you need more help then you should provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: You've identified your main issue: your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  `ggplot2` (and the rest of the tidyverse) is designed to work with tidy data.  Make your data tidy by using `pivot_longer`.  This will give you a data frame with columns (say) `Mean`, `Species`, `Year` and `Value`.  and your life will become much easier.

Comment: The *reason* your data frame is not tidy is that you have information you need to plot (Year and Species) in the *names* of your columns rather than in the *values* they contain.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand yet how it works and how I need to prepare my data !